# How to execute more than one power shell command in a single .ps1 file

Tags: c#, asp.net, powershell, cloud, azure-powershell

I am trying to run more than one powershell command(with parameters in each command) in a single .ps1 file.

i.e.
In the Azure powershell i need to run these 3 commands sequentially

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope LocalMachine -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Force 
Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile 
New-AzureService
```

All the above 3 command receive different parameters. I wanted to keep them in a single .ps1 file.

I am trying as bellow, it is not working although not giving any exception

```
 using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
{
 string Filepath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), @"path of .ps1 file");
 string Script = File.ReadAllText(Filepath);  

 IDictionary Param = new Dictionary<String, String>();
 Param.Add("–PublishSettingsFile", @"path of pubsetting file");
 Param.Add("-ServiceName", CloudServiceName);
 Param.Add("-Location", Location);

var result = 
PowerShell.Create().AddScript(Script).AddParameters(Param).Invoke();
}
```

Comment: Is any one of them invoked for you ?

Comment: @RohitPrakash , I kept this code in a worker role run() method, so it will be executed automatically. Actually i am able to invoke them when i keep them in a separate file and i can even pass parameters. but I wanted to keep them in a single .ps1 file.