# How to run multiple processes in separate windows simultaneously from a single PS1 file?

Tags: powershell, windows-10

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41086814/making-commits-simpler-in-git-using-powershell) and got it working. Being a lazy type, I thought that I could automate the starting process as well. I got the following doing the stuff for me.

```
function GoToWorkApi{
  cd C:\Source\...\api
  git pull
  code .
  dotnet run
  dir
}

function GoToWorkWeb{
  cd C:\Source\...\web
  code .
  npm run dev
  dir
}
```

Now, I'm even more lazy than that and I've tried to put those two in a single file by working [Start-Process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) command. It seems that it gets "stuck" on the *dotnet run* part.

```
function GoToWork{
  cd C:\Source\...\api
  git pull
  code .
  dotnet run

  cd C:\Source\...\web
  code .
  npm run dev
}
```

I'm sensing that I need to open a new PowerShell window and run the individual scripts separately but I haven't got it under controll. How do I do that?

Googlearching leads me only to [Azure related stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28185234/how-to-execute-more-than-one-power-shell-command-in-a-single-ps1-file) and this is plain desktop.

Comment: Use `Start-Process dotnet -args 'run'` instead of `dotnet run`. It will start the process separately.

Comment: @n01d You might post it as a reply, so it can be accepted. If you choose to do that, please make sure to specify not only *start -args* but also *Start-Process -ArgumentList* as some folks like the verbose explicity. You might want to give an example with multiple arguments for *npm run dev*, too. And as a bonus, is it possible to control the opened window's colors? PS is blue on my computer but when starting a process, the window is DOS'y black like in the 90's...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Start-Process` cmdlet instead of `dotnet run`.
Example:

```
Start-Process -FilePath 'dotnet' -ArgumentList 'run'
...
Start-Process -FilePath 'npm' -ArgumentList 'run dev'
```

---

> is it possible to control the opened window's colors

Not sure if you can control it through PS. All that comes to my mind is: `Start-Process -FilePath cmd.exe -ArgumentList '/k color 71 & your_command_here'`.

Comment: As promised...   :)